# Fetch Mongodb data with custom filters from multiple tables

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am getting data from Mongodb like this.

```
 orders = await ordersCollection
 .find(rest)
 .sort({ dateAdded: -1 })
 .skip(parseInt(skip))
 .limit(parseInt(limit))
 .toArray();
```

This query returns data in the orders collection. But in the orders collection I have a userID and I have users table. There is _Id of every user is listed with some of the other data like email. I need that email field. How might it be possible? I have tried $lookup and aggregate but no luck yet. Maybe there is some other technique to use with filters, like sort,skip,limit.

here is both collections look like.

**orders collection**

```
    {"_id":"5d7f276d86250800408856c5","type":"admin-credit",
    "userId":"5d7f074644de5a00b1c0d5c6",
    "fromAccount":"",
    "toAccount":"AUD",
    "amount":20,"fee":0,
    "quote":null,
    "linkId":null,
    "dateAdded":"2019-09-16T06:10:53.554Z",
    "dateApproved":"2019-09-16T06:10:53.614Z",
    "orderStatus":"approved",
    "adminId":"5d7f05b71450370072212b89"}
```

**Users collection**

```
{"_id":"5d7f074644de5a00b1c0d5c6",
"email":"pardeep889@hotmail.com",
"hash":"$2a$10$ocdE3gwsGZR8N5Yauhg1MeKIU11UkKrHynnYWB24x/TWR2WhM/nIu",
"confirmationToken":"e7e0ca1a-cc73-4691-8472-"
"ipAddrs":[{"ip":"192.180.2.15",
"date":"2019-09-16T03:54:03.972Z"}],
"socketToken":"c6a7fc7c-f983-439a-bafa-e93618e0a4e8"
}
```

how I am trying to get the data.

```
   orders = await ordersCollection
        .find(rest)
        .sort({ dateAdded: -1 })
        .skip(parseInt(skip))
        .limit(parseInt(limit))
        .aggregate([
          {
            $lookup: {
              from: "users",
              localField: "user_id",
              foreignField: "_id",
              as: "new record"
            }
          }])
        .toArray();
```

I need the email field with the order.

Comment: can you confirm data type of userId in order collection to be objectId rather than sting.

Comment: need to fetch data from users table just need email everyting working fine I am getting orders data

Comment: Its probable that in one of those collections the `_id` is ObjectID and in one its a string. Is that the case or in both they are strings?

Comment: both are object IDs

Comment: Can you share your code in which you tried lookup or populate etc.

Comment: sure let me add that code too

Comment: I have added that code too please check that

Comment: you can not add aggregate after find query try using populate or you just have to use the aggregate pipeline without find, sort, limit etc.

Comment: Are you using mongoose?

Comment: no not mongoose

Comment: `orders = await ordersCollection.aggregate([
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "user_id",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "new_record"
          }
        }])
        .toArray();` in this case new_record is empty

Comment: @Pardeep just tested the lookup query on shell works fine. Also can't use find and aggregate together. Use `$match` if at all.

Comment: Hi can you please send me your query? I am getting nothing in new_record

Comment: @Pardeep Sure! `db.orders.aggregate([ { $lookup: { from: "users", localField: "userId", foreignField: "_id", as: "userDoc" } }, { $unwind: "$userDoc" } ]);` I guess its a typo in your query `user_id` in the collection doc is `userId`

Comment: just one more thing it return me whole user content I just need email that's it

Comment: @Pardeep Updated that in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) and [`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) in the aggregation pipeline if need be. Also note that I've added [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) for the filter condition:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  { $match: {} },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "userId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "userDoc"
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$userDoc" },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      type: 1,
      userId: 1,
      fromAccount: 1,
      toAccount: 1,
      amount: 1,
      fee: 1,
      quote: 1,
      linkId: 1,
      dateAdded: 1,
      dateApproved: 1,
      orderStatus: 1,
      adminId: 1,
      email: "$userDoc.email"
    }
  }
]);
```

NOTE: `$project` is used to return all fields from `orders` and only email from joined collection documents.